# Access 2007 crashes when started in Win 7 pro standard user

Tags: windows-7, crash, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-access-2007

I have Windows 7 Professional 64-bit on a Dell desktop with Office 2007 Professional installed.

Whenever I open a file in Access as a standard user, it crashes after about a minute of activity, but if I run Access as an administrator, it works fine. Why?

I have a workgroup file defined to use with my old mdb file, if it is of any help.

Would be very grateful if someone could offer a solution.

Comment: Have you tried a different 'standard' user?  It may be something to do with the current user's profile.

Comment: No, It does not work in any standard user I have created.

Comment: Run the setup program in "Program and Features" and choose the "Repair" option 9 times out of 10 it will repair the problem. You could also run SFC /SCANNOW at a Administrator Command Prompt to validate all the DLL. I hope this helps.